# ios break nested loop

Tags: objective-c

If I have a `while` loop with a `for` loop *inside* of the `while` loop, how can I `break` both loops?

I'm doing this because the extra 250ms I get from not completing these loops after I found what I want adds up to be valuable after a while.

pseudocode:

```
while(alwaysTrue) {
    for(NSArray *arr in twoThousandItems) {
        if(IFoundWhatIWasLookingFor) {
            // assign some stuff here
            // break everything, not just the for loop.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all the suggestions so far, seem accurate.  choosing any of them would not be wrong.  the design i would suggest is making the part you want to break out of its own function/method and return from it.  Abstraction is the main power of functional and object-oriented programming - use it.

Comment: Retagged because it's a language question, not an os question. :)

Comment: @bshirley I used `goto` even though I'm a bit leery about it. It's only in one spot in the whole application so I figure it's fine. However, because of some code design changes we were able to switch to a method of your suggestion (which is always my first choice). +1

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is where `goto` is your friend. Yes, that `goto`.

```
while(alwaysTrue) {
    for(NSArray *arr in twoThousandItems) {
        if(IFoundWhatIWasLookingFor) {
            // assign some stuff here
            // break everything, not just the for loop.
            goto BAIL;
        }
    }
}
BAIL:
NSLog(@"Freedom!");
```

The other option is to have short circuits in your loops.

```
while(alwaysTrue && !found) {
    for(NSArray *arr in twoThousandItems) {
        if(IFoundWhatIWasLookingFor) {
            // assign some stuff here
            // break everything, not just the for loop.
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is nobody's friend, `goto` is evil. +1

Comment: After reading up on `goto` it seems that the **overuse** of it is what is evil. While I'm the bigger fan of using return functions as mentioned by *@bshirley*, a `goto` will work for this **one** situation. Thanks & +1

Answer (score 4):

This is one way. This is an applicable technique for other C variants, and other languages as well.

```
bool breakOuterLoop = false;
while(!breakOuterLoop)
{
    for(NSArray *arr in twoThousandItems)
    {
        if(IFoundWhatIWasLookingFor)
        {
            // assign some stuff here
            breakOuterLoop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```