# search NSObject in multidimensional array

Tags: objective-c

In my tableview I have an array with categories and in each category there are multiple products (All those products are NSObjects):

```
category-1:
  - product-1
  - product-3
category-2:
  - product-2
  - ...
```

When I click a button a random product is selected. I need to find the matching product in the array with categories and products. Any tips do do this without much looping?

This is how the data structure is build:

```
for(Category *category in self.categories){
    NSMutableArray *categorydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(Product *product in self.products){
        if(category.catid == product.catid) [categorydata addObject:product];
    }
    [[AppModel sharedInstance].serverDocuments addObject:categorydata];
}
```

Category and Product are custom NSObjects with a catid and a name.

Comment: Need more info to help. Can you provide more information about your data structure? Is a category a class or just a way to organize products in separate arrays? If a class, does it have a `products` property that's an `NSArray` of products? How is the "random" product selected? Can you possibly set up a weak circular reference from a product back to its category? Do you even want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code is silly:

```
for(Category *category in self.categories){
    NSMutableArray *categorydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(Product *product in self.products){
        if(category.catid == product.catid) [categorydata addObject:product];
    }
    [[AppModel sharedInstance].serverDocuments addObject:categorydata];
}
```

If there is only one product where `category.catid == product.catid`, then in your `if` clause you should `break` after you find it: there is no point continuing to loop, because the search is effectively over.

Second, sure, you can *express* this more compactly by such techniques as using NSPredicate and/or key-value coding. But under the hood the loop will still be taking place, so nothing is really gained by that. The problem is that you have not structured this as a dictionary where there is a key that takes you *directly* to the correct entry. If you want that kind of direct access, you will have to restructure the model.

Answer (score 0):

At present your code will go through EVERY product in EVERY category.
You should start by using `break` once you've found the product you're looking for. This will 'break' out of the product loop.

You should then also `break` out of the category loop (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9419013/4633161) or - if you need to loop though subsequent categories you could `continue`.