# How to get out of while loop when data is found in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've written the following code to retrieve `data by date` inside the while loop. Problem is, it's not getting out of the loop when data is found. I think, I missed some code to make extra checking.

Because `print` is working multiple times. Please help me how to solve.

```
while startdate.compare(enddate) != .OrderedDescending {
    let mydate = Config.convertDateTimeFormater(Config.convertDateToString(startdate, fromFormat: 

    let test = [
        "date" : mydate
    ] 
    JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.showInView(self.view, withHeader: "Loading", andFooter: "Please wait")
    Alamofire.request(.POST, Config.checkBookingSlot, parameters: test as? [String : AnyObject], headers: headers, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let msg = swiftyJsonVar["message"].stringValue
            if (swiftyJsonVar["success"]) {
                if let slotData = swiftyJsonVar["data"]["detail"].arrayObject {
                    if slotData.count > 0 {
                        isFound = true
                        print("Break")
                        JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                    } else {
                        JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                        self.showPopup(Config.showPopupMsg)
                    }
                } else {
                    JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                    self.showPopup(Config.showPopupMsg)
                }
            } else {
                JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                isFound = true
            }
        } else {
            JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
            isFound = true
        }
    }
    if isFound {
        break
    }
    startdate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: startdate, options: [])!
}
```

Comment: see this once u get idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418972/ios-break-nested-loop

Comment: Instead of putting  the network call in loop , use `NStimer` or `Performselector` task so that you will be able to check your condition with response. or else your loop will finish before you get first response itself.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving and parsing the JSON data correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are making asynchronous requests within your loop and your isFound variable is set within the closure, so the loop is not waiting on response for those. It's very likely that your loop will finish before you even get the first response.

Answer (score 1):

While loop work in `sync` manner and api calling always work in background means `async` so you need to change your code like this

```
func getData(startDate: NSDate) {
    if (startDate.compare(enddate) != .OrderedDescending) {
        let mydate = Config.convertDateTimeFormater(Config.convertDateToString(startdate, fromFormat:

        let test = [
            "date" : mydate
        ]
        JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.showInView(self.view, withHeader: "Loading", andFooter: "Please wait")
        Alamofire.request(.POST, Config.checkBookingSlot, parameters: test as? [String : AnyObject], headers: headers, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                let msg = swiftyJsonVar["message"].stringValue
                if (swiftyJsonVar["success"]) {
                    if let slotData = swiftyJsonVar["data"]["detail"].arrayObject {
                        if slotData.count > 0 {
                            JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                        }
                        else {
                            JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                            self.showPopup(Config.showPopupMsg)
                            startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: startdate, options: [])!
                            self.getData(startDate)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                        self.showPopup(Config.showPopupMsg)
                        startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: startdate, options: [])!
                        self.getData(startDate)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
                }
            }
            else {
                JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how did you call that function then? I want to sync within date range.

Comment: You have startDate right the date you are using in while loop just use that date to call this function like this way `self.getData(startdate)`

Comment: it's not workable because while loop never wait sync result.

Comment: thats why i have not use loop, check my answer properly

Comment: if there is 4 days different between startdate & enddate, how to use your function?

Comment: Don't understand what you asking can you explain briefly?

Comment: exp: start date is 26-July-2016 and end date is 30-July-2016. There is 4 days different between start date & end date. That's why how can I check for all days with your function.

Comment: I am incrementing the startdate `startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: startdate, options: [])!` just like you did and calling this function again using that date.

Comment: In your question you are setting `isFound` to true for break the loop, in my answer i have not call the function again on that part, I have already give you compete answer. Check properly.