# Alamofire request with while loop

Tags: swift

I need to check the processing status in the loop. need get request

```
func check( completion: @escaping (Bool)->()){
    let url = URL(string: "url")!
    var curStatus = "processing"
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

    while curStatus == "processing" {
        serialQueue.async{
        let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
            Alamofire.request(url,  method: .get, parameters: nil)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }

                    guard let value = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }
                    curStatus = value["status"] as? String ?? "error"
                    if curStatus == "ok" {
                        // do something
                        completion(true)
                        return
                    }
                    if curStatus == "error"{
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }
                    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
            }
            sleep(2)
        CFRunLoopRun()
        }

    }
}
```

Problem : not going in responseJSON. I put breakpoint in

`guard response.result.isSuccess else ...`

and it didn't call it, but breakpoint in line

`Alamofire.request(url, ...` works fine.

How do I fix this?

Sorry for my English. I am just learning it.

Comment: @Mocha nothing, it didnt call call it

Comment: in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609358/how-to-get-out-of-while-loop-when-data-is-found-in-swift is the came problem, if i cant use while loop, how can i solve my task ? (every few second check result of request)

Comment: @Mocha yes, without loop it works fine

Comment: I don't suggest constantly making a network request every few seconds.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mocha i loaded file to server, and i must check when file is ready download it back, I thought: every n seconds to check whether the file is ready, if ready, then download

Comment: When you load the file to server, can the server give a success response to indicate whether the file is ready?

Comment: nope, it can be very long time and this not my server, i cant edit him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think you should be constantly making network requests just to check for a success on the server side. I think you need to redesign your UX.

However.. to try to solve what you're trying to do, I suggest using a timer.

PsuedoCode:

```
let minuteInterval = TimeInterval.minute() * 5
var isMakingRequest = false

let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(minuteInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(checkServer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func checkServer() {
    guard !isMakingRequest else { return }
    isMakingRequest = true
    Do network request {
      self.isMakingRequest = false
    }
}
```